# How protractor runs when using shardTestFiles option

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using the shardTestFiles option with protractor to run my test suites in parallel.

There are some tests that read the same data for different tests, which is expected. The problem is that the routines that read these data has to be protected by some kind of mutex.

What I'd like to know is how protractor run the tests when using the shardTestFiles option? Does it spawn multiple processes (or different threads) for each suite, or it does using a single thread process?

Depending on how it works, I have to decide what kind of mutex mechanism I can use.

Thanks!

Paulo

Comment: http://blog.yodersolutions.com/run-protractor-tests-in-parallel/

Comment: Thanks for the link Barney. I had seen that post before (actually it was from where I learnt about the shardTestFiles). However, it doesn't explain if internally the suites are run in parallel controlled by one or more instances of protractor....